# Class spatie/Analytics/AnalyticsServiceProvider not found

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, laravel-5.4

I just downloaded this package on my localhost.
Spatie/laravel-analytics
its a Google Analytics Package i have followed the documenation of package instead of installing 2.4.0 which is current version of package it installed 1.4.1
[image: spatie/laravel-analytics version 1.4.1]

After installation when i add providers and aliases in config/app.php it shows me errors like this.
[image: providers in config/app.php]
[image: aliases in config/app.php]

And when i publish the config file it shows "Class spatie/Analytics/AnalyticsServiceProvider not found" like this
[image: publish config file]
Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

use `LaravelAnalytics` instead of `Analytics` ,because you are using an old version or upgrade your version of php to php7 and update your composer to get the latest version of the package